# Elasticsearch 5.5 basic suggesters autocomplete not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete feature to the existing elastic search function.

I followed
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester

I'm trying very basic suggecters in the above documentation

```
POST stage-products/searchproduct/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "text" : "bulb",
    "my-suggest-1" : {
      "term" : {
        "field" : "productName"
      }
    },
    "my-suggest-2" : {
       "term" : {
        "field" : "brandName"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

But it does not return any result or any error.
I need to return product names or brand names

[image]

I'm getting the below result when I'm executing my search query
[image]

Comment: How does your mapping look like? i.e. what do you get when running `GET dev-products`?

Comment: @Val I was searching in the wrong index. now I edit my question. Still, I'm not getting any result

Comment: @IsankaThalagala Please remove the images, use code blocks for better help.